# Context Free Grammar for $\{a^mb^n | m+1 \le n\}$

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Trying to make a context free grammar for the above language. The base for this is a common enough problem and I've done some similar ones, but been having trouble with this one.

What a friend and I put together is:

$V = \{a,b,S,A,B\}$

$\Sigma = \{a,b\}$

$R = \{s \to AB|bB, B \to \epsilon, A \to aA|\epsilon \}$

Another friend offered:

$R = \{s \to B|A, A \to aB, B \to bS|\epsilon \}$

I'm not happy with either of them but not sure why. A confirmation, advice, better answer, anything would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be suspicious of those two attempts.

The first grammar will produce `aaa` which should not be in the language.

The second one will produce `aba` which is not in the language either.

---

**Hint.** Note that
$\{a^mb^n \mid m+1 \le n\} 
= \{a^mb^mb^k \mid 1 \le k\}  $.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice those false cases before. Still trying to make your hint work, but came up with this: $\{s \to bB|bA, A \to aS|\epsilon, B \to bS|\epsilon \}$ Does that handle correctly?

Comment: @Bob: No, it still produces `bab` -- and doesn't produce anything that begins with `a` ...

Comment: I meant to say earlier, that hint is actually very helpful, I'm just having trouble turning into a grammar. I have a feeling I'm actually overthinking my attempts. Will keep chipping away at it.

Comment: @Bob: Have you seen a grammar for $\{a^mb^m\mid m\ge 0\}$? Your attempts seem to be missing the essential feature of that.

Comment: Yeah: $S \to aSb|ab|\epsilon$ (think I got that right). I took another look a few minutes ago, not sure how my friends and I got to our original attempts. 

Assuming I didn't screw the one in this comment up, it's why I think I'm overthinking things.

Comment: Third time's the charm?

$S \to aAb | Ab$,

$A \to S|bC$,

$C \to b|\epsilon$

This requires at least a 'b'. For every 'a' there is a 'b', and then at least one more (I hope - that's what I was going for anyway). I don't see any extraneous outputs either. Thoughts?

Comment: @Bob: I _think_ that will work, though it seems rather complex, and it's not quite clear what the _idea_ behind the complexity is. Why not simply $$ \begin{align} S &\to XY \\ X &\to aXb \mid \varepsilon \\ Y &\to bY \mid b \end{align} $$ or even just $$ S \to aSb \mid Sb \mid b $$

Comment: No wait, your latest attempt doesn't generate `b`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Both your hint, and your continued evaluation of my efforts! And for your answer, which is hilariously more elegant than my attempts.